# How to split and convert into dictionary and swap the key value

Tags: python

i have list list

`["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A"  ]`

- I need to convert Dictionary
- I need to split by +
- Convert into dictionary and swap the values
- if the values are present then no need to process

Expected is dictionary `{"A":["Germany", "France"],"B":["England"] }`

code is below, i got the output as dictionary only and need to insert one condition `if the values are present then no need to process`

```
l = ["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A"  ]
m = []
for i in l:
    m.append(i.split('+'))
for k,v in m:
    n ={k:v}
    print({v: k for k, v in n.items()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
l = ["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A", "Nigeria" ]
m = {}

for s in l:
    try:
        country = country.strip()
        category = category.strip()

        foo = m.setdefault(category, [])
        
        if country not in foo:
            foo.append(country)
    except ValueError as e:
        pass


print(m)
```

Comment: @Programmer This answers the question. I don't see why a downvote is necessary.

Comment: @Programmer If you think this is complicated, I don't know what to say. It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: upvoting, can you check above scenario

Comment: @sim Edit made, please see new answer.

Comment: we are appending to ` foo = m.setdefault(category, [])` why automatically its chaning `m` ALSO

Comment: @sim This is a "gotcha" of Python. You're expecting that `foo` and and `m[category]` are two different lists, right? But `foo` is actually a pointer to `m[category]`.

Comment: one last thing, your answer is `{'A': ['Germany', 'France'], 'B': ['England'], None: ['Nigeria']}
` but i want `{'A': ['Germany', 'France'], 'B': ['England']}` since there is no `+` for Nigeria we dont add that particular key

Comment: @sim In that case, we can just catch the exception thrown when the result of the string split has too few elements. Please see new edit.

Answer (score 3):

I think opting for a readable solution here is best.

Loop through the list `l`, and then do the split on `' + '`.

Then, append the country names to the appropriate key the *first* time they are encountered.

Notice the use of `collections.defaultdict` to initialize the dictionary as a dict of lists.

```
import collections

l = ["Germany + A", "France + A", "England + B", "Germany + A"]

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for i in l:
    k, v = i.split(' + ')
    if k not in d[v]:
        d[v].append(k)

print(dict(d))
```

This gives the output:

```
{'A': ['Germany', 'France'], 'B': ['England']}
```

If you want to stick with your original approach, you could again split using `' + '`, and put the result into a list using a list comprehension:

```
m = [i.split(' + ') for i in l]
```

Then, you would loop through `m` like this:

```
for k, v in m:
    if k not in d[v]:
        d[v].append(k)
```

This is useful if you want the intermediate `m` list.

Comment: You should initiate the defaultdict with `set` instead of `list`, and then use `d[v].add` instead of `d[v].append`. The check if k not yet present then can be removed.

Comment: +1 for using defaultdict, the right tool for the job. I don't know why the other answers are using `.setdefault` manually

Comment: @programmer "should" is questionable here. Its not clear whether this would be appropriate. I did think of using a `set` and was about to, but then it would be a dict of sets rather than a dict of lists, so I stuck with a list instead. Either way is fine I guess (its a simple change).

Comment: yes, unless the OP wants to do this with millions of strings, it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = ["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A"  ]
result = {}
for item in my_list:
    country, key = item.split(' + ')
    if country not in result.setdefault(key, []):
        result[key].append(country)
print(result)
```

As a side note - use meaningful names, not cryptic one-char names.

As an alternative to using `dict.setdefault()` one can use `collections.defaultdict` with default value of `list` or if the order is not important - `set`

EDIT: comparison between using `dict.setdefault` and `collections.defaultdict(list)`

```
from collections import defaultdict
from timeit import timeit

my_list = ["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A"  ]

def test1(my_list):
  result = {}
  for item in my_list:
      country, key = item.split(' + ')
      if country not in result.setdefault(key, []):
          result[key].append(country)
  return result

def test2(my_list):
  result = defaultdict(list)
  for item in my_list:
      country, key = item.split(' + ')
      if country not in result[key]:
          result[key].append(country)
  return result

print(timeit('test1(my_list)', setup='from __main__ import test1, my_list', number=100000))
print(timeit('test2(my_list)', setup='from __main__ import test2, my_list', number=100000))
```

output

```
0.2819225169987476
0.3298255940026138
```

at least with small sample data `setdefault` is a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

#### Another way to achieve this

There's a great Python lib called [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) which can also do some nice job and give you some flexibility to play with:

```py
# Input
L = ["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A"  ]

# Preprocessing
L = [l.split(' + ') for l in L]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['country','type']) # give the columns some names
```

See what's in df:

```
>>> df
   country type
0  Germany    A
1   France    A
2  England    B
3  Germany    A
```

```
# Then, drop duplicate records:
df.drop_duplicates(['country', 'type'], inplace=True)

# Group by type, convert to list for each record and dump to a dict in one shot
grouped = df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x: x['country'].tolist()).to_dict()
```

And the result:

```
>>> grouped
{'A': ['Germany', 'France'], 'B': ['England']}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the efficient solution but there are multiple solutions to

multiple questions framed into one

```
from itertools import groupby

s=["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A"  ]

m=[i.strip(' ').split('+') for i in s]
[['Germany ', ' A'], ['France ', ' A'], ['England ', ' B'], ['Germany ', ' A']]

#Grouping based on alphabets 'A' , B
new=[list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(m,reverse=True), lambda x:x[1])]
[[['Germany ', ' A'], ['Germany ', ' A'], ['France ', ' A']],
[['England ', ' B']]]


#swapping alphabet and Countries position
new=[item[::-1] for sublist in new for item in sublist ]
[[' A', 'Germany '], [' A', 'Germany '], [' A', 'France '], [' B', 'England       ']]


dct = dict((key, tuple(v for (k, v) in pairs)) 
           for (key, pairs) in itertools.groupby(new, lambda pair: pair[0]))
{' A': ('Germany ', 'Germany ', 'France '), ' B': ('England ',)}


{k:list(set(v)) for k,v in dct.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
l = ["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A"  ]
m = []
dicct = {}
for i in l:
    m.append(i.split('+'))
for k,v in m:
    if v in dicct:
        if k not in dicct[v]:
            dicct[v].append(k)
    else:
        dicct[v] = []
        dicct[v].append(k)

print(dicct)
```

Comment: can you check one more scenario, l = ["Germany + A", "France + A",  "England + B", "Germany + A" , "Nigeria" ], in this also same output since there is no '+'after "Nigeria"

Comment: upvoting, can you check above scenario